# ruby hash to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, hash

I have a hash of items which I'm getting via Freebase.  I want to include it as I would a model inside a rails form_for.

ie (i'm using formtastic) , this works on a model...

```
<%= f.input :source, :as => :select, :collection => @subject.types, :member_label => :name, :member_value => :id, :input_html => { :class => 'combobox' } %>
```

But not on my hash.

My question is how can I use an external source with the rails form_for helpers and whether this is a route I should take.  I'm sure I could take another route using the form_tag and then cycle through the simple ruby hash, but thought maybe using the rails methods would be more elegant and maintainable?  I'm also not storing the freebase data, just the ID.

Simplified Array/Hash:

```
[{:name=>"US President", :value=>"/m/02mjmr"}, {:name=>"Election campaign", :value=>"/m/047qllg"}, {:name=>"Event", :value=>"/m/057l6lw"}]
```

or the complete hash of freebase search results:

```
[{"mid"=>"/m/02mjmr", "name"=>"Barack Obama", "notable"=>{"name"=>"US President", "id"=>"/government/us_president"}, "lang"=>"en", "score"=>156.429855}, {"mid"=>"/m/047qllg", "name"=>"Barack Obama presidential campaign, 2008, General Election", "notable"=>{"name"=>"Election campaign", "id"=>"/government/election_campaign"}, "lang"=>"en", "score"=>58.741718}, {"mid"=>"/m/057l6lw", "name"=>"Barack Obama 2009 presidential inauguration", "notable"=>{"name"=>"Event", "id"=>"/event/event"}, "lang"=>"en", "score"=>57.407536}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to easily do this as so:

```
<%= f.collection_select :freebase_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@freebase_hash, :value, :name, @object.freebase_id)
```

The @object.freebase_id is passed to options_from_collection_for_select so that it can specify which (if any) are selected when the view is loaded. This is important for edit actions, or for new actions when redisplaying the form after validation errors.